# PSQL Restore Process Failed saying "pg_restore: error: could not execute query: no connection to the server"

Tags: database, postgresql, data-import

I have a database backup of around 450MBs. I want to restore the database to Amazon Lightsail managed database with 2vCPU and 1 GB ram. I also have enabled Data Migration Import Mode to not get any interruption while importing data (recommended way).

Database restore process starts successfully and it takes around 3 hours but suddenly this process failed by throwing this error

> pg_restore: error: could not execute query: no connection to the server

I have started the process again and it again failed after 3 hours throwing same error. My internet is stable and my database is active. I couldn't figure it out what's could be the reason for that.

Comment: Check https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90258/pg-restore-archiver-db-could-not-execute-query-error-schema-public-alre

Comment: This is a different error that you are referring to.

Comment: As far as I know, lightsail is not a database.  But it does work with databases.  But what is the actual database?

Comment: Is that the entirely of the error message?  I would have expected more to it than that.  Does the db log file give more info?  Was there a previous log message?

Comment: Yes, you are right, Amazon lightsail isn't a database but when we use lightsail it has a separate section of managed database from where people with less technical background can create databases easily. It's actually a more simplified version of RDS, in the backend it is using RDS.

Comment: Yes, you are right again. I was missing some logs on the top. Previously, I was reading the last one, there were different error logs also available on the top.

Comment: @jjanes I am facing pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR: extension "pgagent" is not available. Do you have any idea how to install pgagent for my Amazon lightsail managed database?

Answer (score 0):

I think that pgagent is not supported on RDS.  If pgagent is central to your app, you will need to find another solution, like not using RDS, or changing your app not to use pgagent.

But usually pg_restore will create all the extensions needed as one of the first things it does, so I don't understand how they takes 3 hours to notice this, nor why the problem manifests with the follow-up error you get. I don't get "no connection to server error".  What I do get depends on what options were given to pg_restore.  So this presentation of these issues might be lightsail/RDS specific.

If pgagent is peripheral to your app, then you if have still have access to the original server you could drop that extension and redo the dump.  If not, you could restore the dump onto a community version of PostgreSQL, drop the extension, and redo the dump.  The problem is that this might be just the tip of the iceberg, and you might uncover many other compatibility issues, and it would suck to do this one at a time.

If you want to preview of what is going on, maybe you could do something like:

```
pg_restore dmp.dmp -f - | fgrep -in 'create extension'
```

To see all the extensions the restoration is going to try to make and how early in the session it will try to make them.